# Out of memory when reading many bodies with play-ws

Tags: scala, playframework

When reading multiple bodies from a server using play WS standalone I get a OOM:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding$StringEncoder.encode(StringCoding.java:300)
    at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:344)
    at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:918)
    at akka.util.CompactByteString$.apply(ByteString.scala:872)
    at akka.util.ByteString$.apply(ByteString.scala:51)
    at play.api.mvc.Codec$.$anonfun$javaSupported$1(Results.scala:346)
    at play.api.mvc.Codec$$$Lambda$846/1241362979.apply(Unknown Source)
    at play.api.http.DefaultWriteables.$anonfun$wString$1(Writeable.scala:171)
    at play.api.http.DefaultWriteables$$Lambda$849/1109231015.apply(Unknown Source)
    at play.api.http.Writeable.toEntity(Writeable.scala:25)
    at play.api.mvc.Results$Status.apply(Results.scala:429)
    ...
```

You can reproduce it with the following example:

```scala
val bigString: String = (1 to 1000000).mkString("")

val serverConfig = ServerConfig(port = Some(findFreeTcpRandomPort()))
val server = AkkaHttpServer.fromRouterWithComponents(serverConfig) { components =>
  import Results._
  import components.{defaultActionBuilder => Action}
{
  case GET(p"/big") => Action {
    Ok(bigString)
  }
}
}

val url = s"http://localhost:${server.httpPort.get}/big"
implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

val ws = StandaloneAhcWSClient()
try {
  val f = Future.traverse((1 to 1000).toList) { _ =>
    ws.url(url).get().map(_ => ())
  }
  Await.result(f, 1 hour)
} finally {
  ws.close()
  server.stop()
  system.terminate()
}
```

Using the libraries:

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-ahc-ws-standalone" % "2.0.3"
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-akka-http-server" % "2.6.21"
```

It seems that the ws client is accumulating the responses without cleaning them.
If I create and close a new client for each request then it works.

Any idea how can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running too many requests in parallel, esspecially when each body of your response is at least of length `5888896`.

To prove that the issue isn't with the ws client, I've split the requests into 100 chunks and only start the next 100 chunks when the previous chunk is complete.

```
  val url                             = s"http://localhost:${server.httpPort.get}/big"
  implicit val system: ActorSystem    = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val ws = StandaloneAhcWSClient()
  try {
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
    run100Requests()
  } finally {
    ws.close()
    server.stop()
    system.terminate()
  }

  def run100Requests(): Unit = {
    val f = Future.traverse((1 to 100).toList) { _ =>
      ws.url(url).get().map(_ => ())
    }
    Await.result(f, 1 hour)
  }
```

I'm no longer getting OOM errors when I do this.

Thus I think you should be introducing some limit to the number of in-flight requests. (Don't use Await.result obviously)

The best way to do that is probably to chunk your list of inputs and send requests for each chunk.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I simplify this case for the example as I am using `Task` (monix) and `traverse` in this case is sequential.
But it help me find that even if a was using `Task` I was still starting the `Future` at the creation of the `Task` (using `fromFuture`) and not at the execution and using `deferFuture` resolved the problem.